# swift ios8 call phone number whit openURL is very slow

Tags: swift, ios8

This code works correctly, but is delayed by 10 seconds from the action you call the function until the opening.

```
var phoneNumberEx: String = "595973455888"
let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumberEx)")
let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
      application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        application.openURL(phoneCallURL)
    })
}
```

Comment: It fixes the problem for me.